# How to set a tag for a user in one signal with rest api

Tags: c#, rest, push-notification, onesignal

According to [one signal documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/data-tags#section-tags) tag can be set with rest API:

> Tags are data attributes that can be added to users via OneSignal SDKs or the Server REST API.

but there is no more data, about how to send a tag with rest api! the link just refer to create notification documentation and nothing more.

Is it possible to send tag from back-end? Does any one experience this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OneSignal describe this issue under [edit device](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#edit-device) section in it's documentation:

by using playerId in calling this web service with **PUT** method:

> https://onesignal.com/api/v1/players/{playerid}

and in body:

```
{
 "app_id": "Your app id",
 "tags" : {
    "add_new_tag":"joined",
    "remove_old_tag" : ""
    }
}
```

> To delete a tag, include its key and set its value to blank. Omitting
>   a key/value will not delete it. For example, if I wanted to delete two
>   existing tanks rank and category while simultaneously adding a new tag
>   class, the tags JSON would look like the following:

```
"tags": {
           "rank": "",
           "category": "",
           "class": "my_new_value"
        }
```

Comment: The above methods is not recommended anymore. You can use the respective SDK instead of calls to the rest API as described [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section--sendtag-).

Comment: I know, but sometimes I have to  send tagg from backEnd, and I there is no other way for that times

Comment: @RezaM.A bro. Can you please take a look at this query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72725883/how-to-add-tag-to-onesignal-using-android-web-view-app