# How to add Tag to OneSignal using Android Web View app?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-webview, onesignal

I have a web view app with OneSignal integrated into it. All I'm trying to do is add tags to that user when clicked on a button in OneSignal using the below code :

```
<button onclick="buttonclicked()" >some</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async=""></script>
<script>
  window.OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
  OneSignal.push(function() {
    OneSignal.init({
      appId: "xxxxx",
    });
  });
  
  
function buttonclicked() {
    console.log("click");
    OneSignal.push(function() {
     OneSignal.sendTags({sub_url:window.location.href, topic:'tags'}).then(function(tagsSent) {
         console.log("tagssent:" + JSON.stringify(tagsSent));
     });
    });
}
</script>
```

I followed exactly the same procedure as in the [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/add-user-data-tags)

Not sure what went wrong, when I trigger the function through the app, the data is not being posted to OneSignal's tags field.

Any help is greatly appreciated.